# How to compare 2 strings alphabetically in PHP?

Tags: php, string, sorting

What the title says. Specifically if I have

```
$array1['name'] = 'zoo';
$array2['name'] = 'fox';
```

How can I determine that alphabetically `$array2`'s name should come above `$array1`'s?

Comment: You might find [`s($array1['name'])->compareTo($array2['name'])`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L495) or [`s($array1['name'])->compareToIgnoreCase($array2['name'])`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L514) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use `strcmp`. If the first argument to strcmp is lexicographically smaller to the second, then the value returned will be negative. If both are equal, then it will return 0. And if the first is lexicograpically greater than the second then a positive number will be returned.

nb. You probably want to use `strcasecmp(string1,string2)`, which ignores case...

Answer (score 15):

You can compare both strings with [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp):

> Returns < 0 if *str1* is less than *str2*; > 0 if *str1* is greater than *str2*, and 0 if they are equal.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a little late (then again I wasn't a programmer yet in 2009 :-) No one mentioned this yet, but you can simply use the operators which you use on number as well.

`< > <= >= == !=` and more

For example:

`'a' > 'b'` returns `false`

`'a' < 'b'` returns `true`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

**IMPORTANT**

There is a flaw, which you can find in the comments below.

Comment: Man, this is definitely the best answer for this thread and it didn't have a single upvote! If you only need to compare two strings to simply find the one which comes first in alphabetical order, it is definitely the lighter, most clever solution. Yet, so stupid it almost hurts.

Comment: @MarcosBuarque: I appreciate it. I was just 8 years too late with my answer :-)

Comment: This does *not* work as expected. For example `'10' < '2'` evaluates to false even though the string `'10'` should come before `'2'` if you compare *alphabetically* (which is what the question is about). This is because whenever strings look like integers PHP automatically converts them to integers and compares them numerically instead of alphabetically. You should go with `strcmp()` as suggested if your goal is to really compare alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

I often use `natsort` ([Natural Sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)), since I usually just want to preserve the array for later use anyway.

Example:

```
natsort($unsorted_array);

var_dump($usorted_array); // will now be sorted.
```

Answer (score 1):

[sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

EDIT just realised values from different arrays, could [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) first but not sure thats what you want